# Google Sheets Formula Issue

Tags: google-sheets-formula

We are facing some issues with google sheets, write a formula {**=IF(A1,A1,IF(B1="","",NOW()))**} when dore did his work on time Timestamp come same but when he come next day open the sheet Timestamp was a change on that time when he was open.

But this formula is already working with multiple google sheets and some google sheets are working properly and some are not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZFhT.jpg)

So, please help me with the same

Answer (score 0):

instead of this, use now() formula in any cell and lock the cell in if  formula
write now in d1
like this

=if(a1,a1,if(a1<>"",$d$1,""))

Comment: Hi, Satyendra I also use this formula but still, this also changes the date and time when the sheet is open in next day.

Comment: =if(MH7,MH7,if(MI7<>"",$A$1,""))

Comment: If This Is Not Working You Can Go For Script And Use Trigger For This